gulp returns immediately when the condition is met
const min = () => {
  if (data.config.min) {
    // When the condition is true, I want to return immediately and skip the following process
    return; // error here
  } else {
    return (
      gulp.src(['./prod/*.js'])
      .pipe(uglify()).
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./server/js/'))
      )
    );
  }
};

I'm using gulp 5, is there any good way for me to do this?
This task is chained with other tasks using gulp.series, so I understand that I should use return to confirm that the task is completed.
